# Drupal7 Views: Grouping by Date Over a Range

Tags: view, drupal-7

Creating a view of events over time.  Some events are one day events - some stretch over multiple days.  Some are repeating events.  What I would like to do is create a view that shows all the events for day 1, then for day 2, and so on.

For example:

```
Event 1 - happens every Monday in May
Event 2 - happens the first full week of May - 5/5-5/11
Event 3 - happens Tuesday May 7th
```

So the View would show:

```
Monday, May 6th
 - Event 1
 - Event 2

Tuesday May 7th
 - Event 2
 - Event 3

Wednesday May 8th
  - Event 2
```

And so on.  Any suggestion on how can I group to create this?  Or do I need to alter the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use Drupal Calendar: http://drupal.org/project/calendar

It automatically creates views in days, weeks, months, etc.